# Put text with line breaks in the editor and make it look good

Tags: javascript, text, formatting

I am a beginner in javascript and I have a problem and I do not know how to put text with many line breaks in addition to putting variables,I know that there is another way that is to put the text and the variables in a stright line but I would like another way,since I have a lot of text and I wish I could read it and modify it to my liking. :)

My question is how can I do this without having to make a straight line in the code?

**I would like to have something like this in my code and being able to add variables to it**

```
function procesDATA (LINKS, DATAINF, State, Callback) {
        console.log(DATAINF);
        console.log(LINKS);


        var text = "Lorem ipsum"+ DATAINF.geo + "dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        "Sed hendrerit sapien sit amet mattis facilisis." `+ DATAINF.name +` "Donec dolor mi, 
        dapibus nec sollicitudin ut, pulvinar" "eu" "ex. Maecenas nec faucibus turpis. Vestibulum 
        ante erat.`+ DATAINF.date`";

        fs.writeFile(DATAINF.gamename + ".txt", text,"utf-8", function(err) {
            let OK = ["Archivo Guardado"]; console.log(OK);
        }); 
    }
```

Thank you very much to those who can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The new way

Using "[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)", text will be verbatum in between the `tick` marks -- including new lines and leading tabs:

```
var text = `Lorem ipsum ${DATAINF.geo} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
"Sed hendrerit sapien sit amet mattis facilisis." ${DATAINF.name} "Donec dolor mi, 
dapibus nec sollicitudin ut, pulvinar" "eu" "ex. Maecenas nec faucibus turpis. Vestibulum 
ante erat. ${DATAINF.date}`;
```

To integrate varibles wrap them with ${ varible in here }

#### The old way

While reliable, it's clunky has many caveat's... You have to understand how to wrap quotes and/or escape single/double quotes. (I chose to wrap with single quotes because the text contained many double quotes.)

```
var newline = "\n"; // if windows maybe use "\r\n"

var text = 'Lorem ipsum ' + DATAINF.geo + ' dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ' + newline;
text += 'Sed hendrerit sapien sit amet mattis facilisis. ' + DATAINF.name + ' Donec dolor mi, ' + newline;
text += 'dapibus nec sollicitudin ut, pulvinar" "eu" "ex. Maecenas nec faucibus turpis. Vestibulum ' + newline;
text += 'ante erat. ' + DATAINF.date + newline;
```

#### Wrap and/or escape quotes

NOTE: Only for the "old way"... you *_don't_* have to deal with this if using the "new way"

You can use single quotes to wrap double quotes:

```
var foo = 'this has a double quote" in here';
```

Or you can use double quotes to wrap single quotes:

```
var foo = "this has a single quote' in here";
```

If you have both single and double quotes, you have to escape the one's that match the wrapper with a backslash:

```
// since we wrap with double, escape the inner double with a backslash  
var foo = "this has \" both in ' here"; 

// since we wrap with single, escape the inner single with a backslash
var foo = 'this has " both in \' here';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and your time you have helped me a much

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Unless your question is just about how to format in the editor in which case

just do this.

```
"The question brown fox " + object.info + 
"Jumped over " + object.otherinfo +
"The lazy " + object.extrainfo + 
"dog"
```

### i dont know why you have the extra ` in your ideal string.

unless you are talking about formatting the final output content in a file in which case you can just add

`\n`

where you want new lines.

[For more information](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = `Lorem ipsum ${DATAINF.geo} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n Sed hendrerit sapien sit amet mattis facilisis.\n ${DATAINF.name} Donec dolor mi, dapibus nec sollicitudin ut, pulvinar" "eu" "ex. Maecenas nec faucibus turpis. Vestibulum ante erat.\n ${DATAINF.date}`;
```